# Java nullPointerException help needed

Tags: java

```
public class Store {
public Server q[];
public Thread t[];


public Store()
{
    for(int j=0;j<=5;j++)
    {
     q[j]=new Server(j);
    t[j]=new Thread(q[j]);
    }
}
```

it gives me nullPointerException at q[j]=new Server(j); how so?

Comment: you never initialize q.

Comment: Off topic. Choose sensible names for your variables...

Comment: When you do `public Server q[];` value of `q` becomes `null` and you can't use `[x]` on `null` like `null[x]`. You need to explicitly initialize your `q` like `Server q[] = new Server[someSize]`. Then you will be able to put some value inside this array.

Comment: Also be aware that you cannot grow arrays once they are initialised.